# H2 - Multiple applications access same H2 database

Tags: java, h2

I am using embedded database **H2** in 2 web applications say **WebApp1** and **WebApp2**. I run WebApp1 and execute some query to access H2 database. Mean while I run WebApp2, but it throws exception that **H2 is currently been used by another process**

My need is, I should be able to use H2 database by WebApp1 and WebApp2 at the same time. I analysed the below link but it tells about multiple connections but not about multiple applications.

```
http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#multiple_connections
```

Comment: Multiple applications making simultaneous multiple connections, same thing, you should be running H2 in server mode

Comment: You cannot share a database between applications while in embedded mode. Check the documentation for different ways of running the database.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the embedded mode for WebApp1 and the server mode for WebApp2: in order to get this trick, both urls must be like "jdbc:h2:mydb;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE"

More info here: http://h2database.com/html/features.html#auto_mixed_mode